# How to make one button work for all the inputs

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am trying to translate all inputs with their respective translated language outputs using a **button**

When I click the "Translate" Button it works but not for the respective languages, the output language gets altered.

Each output language from the Selection should be fixed, for Spanish Output, the second selection should be fixed with Spanish, for Dutch Output, the second selection should be fixed with Dutch, and so on. (Each time no bother to select)

**Second selection for each is the output language which should be fixed for each in the HTML `<option>` tag**

And hence when clicked "translate" it should translate all the respective input.

```js
const countries = {
  "ar-SA": "Arabic",
  "bn-IN": "Bengali",
  "da-DK": "Danish",
  "de-DE": "German",
  "el-GR": "Greek",
  "en-GB": "English",
  "es-ES": "Spanish",
  "fa-IR": "Persian",
  "fi-FI": "Finnish",
  "fr-FR": "French",
  "gu-IN": "Gujarati",
  "hi-IN": "Hindi",
  "hu-HU": "Hungarian",
  "id-ID": "Indonesian",
  "it-IT": "Italian",
  "ja-JP": "Japanese",
  "kn-IN": "Kannada",
  "ko-KR": "Korean",
  "ku-TR": "Kurdish",
  "la-VA": "Latin",
  "my-MM": "Burmese",
  "ne-NP": "Nepali",
  "nl-NL": "Dutch",
  "ur-PK": "Pakistani",
  "pa-IN": "Panjabi",
  "pl-PL": "Polish",
  "pt-PT": "Portuguese",
  "ro-RO": "Romanian",
  "ru-RU": "Russian",
  "sq-AL": "Albanian",
  "sr-RS": "Serbian",
  "sv-SE": "Swedish",
  "ta-LK": "Tamil",
  "te-IN": "Telugu",
  "th-TH": "Thai",
  "tr-TR": "Turkish",
  "uk-UA": "Ukrainian",
  "vi-VN": "Vietnamese"
};
const fromText = document.querySelectorAll(".from-text", ".from-text2"),
  toText = document.querySelectorAll(".to-text", ".to-text2"),
  selectTag = document.querySelectorAll("select");

(translateBtn = document.getElementById("btn4all")),
  selectTag.forEach((tag, id) => {
    for (let country_code in countries) {
      let selected =
        id == 0
          ? country_code == "en-GB"
            ? "selected"
            : ""
          : country_code == "es-ES"
          ? "selected"
          : "";
      let option = `<option ${selected} value="${country_code}">${countries[country_code]}</option>`;
      tag.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", option);
    }
  });

fromText.forEach((el, index) => {
  if(!el.value){
    toText[index].value = "";
  }
});
function translate(fromEl, toEl, language){
    let text = fromEl.value.trim();
    let translateFrom = "en-GB"; //I've hard-coded this as there's only 1 select tag per row? Something to consider
    let translateTo = language.value;
    
    if(!text){
        return;
    }

    toEl.setAttribute("placeholder", "Translating...");
    let apiUrl = `https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=${text}&langpair=${translateFrom}|${translateTo}`;

    fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            toText.value = data.responseData.translatedText;
            data.matches.forEach((data) => {
                if (data.id === 0) {
                    toEl.value = data.translation;
                }
            });
            toEl.setAttribute("placeholder", "Translation");
        });
}

translateBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //this button is the first button on the page so we'll hard-code the first elements for now
    translate(fromText[0], toText[0], selectTag[0]);
});

document.getElementById("btn4all").addEventListener("click", () => {
    //here I am assuming that there are matching numbers of from, to, and language dropdowns - worth considering

    for(let i = 0; i < fromText.length; i++){
        translate(fromText[i], toText[i], selectTag[i]);
    }
});
```

```css
.radioact {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.input-group {
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  width: 75.666667%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.btn3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #05203e;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.transs {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 15%;
  margin-right: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">

  <input type="text" value="" class="to-text form-control" name="name_eslang" placeholder="Spanish Word">

  <input spellcheck="false" value="Translate word" id="translatename" class="from-text" placeholder="Type to Translate">

  <ul class="transs">
    <li class="row from"><select></select>
    </li>
    <li class="row to"><select></select>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="input-group">

  <input type="text" value="" class="to-text form-control" name="name_eslang" placeholder="Dutch Word">

  <input spellcheck="false" value="Translate word" id="translatename" class="from-text" placeholder="Type to Translate">

  <ul class="transs">
    <li class="row from"><select></select>
    </li>

    <li class="row to">
      <select>
      </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="input-group">

  <input type="text" value="" class="to-text form-control" name="name_eslang" placeholder="Hindi Word">

  <input spellcheck="false" value="Translate word" id="translatename" class="from-text" placeholder="Type to Translate">

  <ul class="transs">
    <li class="row from"><select></select>
    </li>
    <li class="row to">
      <select>
      </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="input-group">

  <input type="text" value="" class="to-text form-control" name="name_eslang" placeholder="Portuguese Word">

  <input spellcheck="false" value="Translate word" id="translatename" class="from-text" placeholder="Type to Translate">

  <ul class="transs">
    <li class="row from"><select></select>
    </li>
    <li class="row to">
      <select>
      </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<span id="btn4all" class="btn3">Translate</span>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns the first matching element. `document.querySelectorAll` returns all the matching elements, but your code will then need updating to process an array

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I'd suggest changing `fromText = document.querySelector(` to `fromText = document.querySelectorAll(`, which now returns an array of all the matching elements - do the same for `toText` too.

I'd suggest splitting the code from `translateBtn.addEventListener` into its own function

```
function translate(fromEl, toEl, languageFrom, languageTo){
    let text = fromEl.value.trim();
    let translateFrom = languageFrom.value
    let translateTo = languageTo.value;
    
    if(!text){
        return;
    }

    if(languageFrom == languageTo){
        alert("Languages must be different!");
        return;
    }

    toEl.setAttribute("placeholder", "Translating...");
    let apiUrl = `https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=${text}&langpair=${translateFrom}|${translateTo}`;

    fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            toText.value = data.responseData.translatedText;
            data.matches.forEach((data) => {
                if (data.id === 0) {
                    toEl.value = data.translation;
                }
            });
            toEl.setAttribute("placeholder", "Translation");
        });
}
```

Then we can reuse this, either for adding extra translate buttons or for our "translate all" button. The button click to call this would become this:

```
translateBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //this button is the first button on the page so we'll hard-code the first elements for now
    translate(fromText[0], toText[0], selectTag[0], selectTag[1]);
});
```

Alternatively, adding more buttons would give us code something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".btn3").forEach((el, index) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", () => {
        translate(fromText[i], toText[i], selectTag[i * 2], selectTag[(i * 2) + 1]);
    });
});
```

Anyways, now that we have our `translate` function separated, we can start that magical "translate all" function - it actually looks very similar to our code for having many translate buttons!

```
document.getElementById("btn4all").addEventListener("click", () => {
    //here I am assuming that there are matching numbers of from, to, and language dropdowns - worth considering

    for(let i = 0; i < fromText.length; i++){
        translate(fromText[i], toText[i], selectTag[i * 2], selectTag[(i * 2) + 1]);
    }
});
```

(as an aside, it is probably worth reviewing your IDs and classes - `.btn3` and `#btn4all` are not the most descriptive names! Consider instead, `.btn-translate` (or `.btn.translate`) and `#translateAll` (or `#translateAll.btn`))

---

As mentioned in the comments, `fromText` now becomes an array - so your event listener there will need to look different. Try something like this:

```
//an exact replacement - only listening for the first element
fromText[0].addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  if (!fromText[0].value) {
    toText[0].value = "";
  }
});

//OR - listening for all
fromText.forEach((el, index) => {
  if(!el.value){
    toText[index].value = "";
  }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: fromText.addEventListener is not a function
: https://codepen.io/theAnonymousGirl/pen/PoarwBw

Comment: Anyways, it sounds like you've taken the suggestion and changed `fromText` to use `querySelectorAll`. This now means that `fromText` is an array, so you will need to loop through each element to add the event listeners. This can be done using `forEach`, e.g. `fromText.forEach(text => { text.addEventListener(...)});`

Comment: I followed fromtext too; error: https://codepen.io/theAnonymousGirl/pen/yLEdymp

Comment: Ah my bad, there's a typo in the `translate` function - I'll update my answer now, but that should be `fromEl.value.trim()` not `fromText`!

Comment: you can use JSFiddle either or this above link of codepen to recheck

Comment: Change each dropdown selection,and translate for each at once, first output does not work: https://codepen.io/theAnonymousGirl/pen/QWxXbEq

Comment: It appears I misread your code and missed the hidden select, I've made a change to address that. Do you understand what this code is doing though, as these have been minor tweaks? Also - I can't save the codepen as it's tied to your account, so you will have to make these changes yourself over there

Comment: I updated again Can you tweak only for "Translate for each at once" button  and remove each translate button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250399/discussion-between-anonymous-girl-and-luke).

Comment: Started Bounty https://jsfiddle.net/